# Woocommerce: Getting data from latest order

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, mysqli, woocommerce

So far I have been able to get the `ID` of the latest completed order that was made using this:

```
<?php

function get_last_order_id(){
  global $wpdb;
  $statuses = "wc-completed";

  // Getting last Order ID (max value)
  $results = $wpdb->get_col( "
      SELECT MAX(ID) FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts
      WHERE post_type LIKE 'shop_order'
      AND post_status IN ('$statuses')
  " );
 return reset($results);
}

$latest_order_id = get_last_order_id();
echo ($latest_order_id);
```

However, instead of getting the `ID`, i would like to get the `billing_first_name`. Does anyone know how to get it?

Comment: Do you mean billing firstname?

Comment: Yes that's what I mean

Comment: You can simply use `get_billing_first_name` method. for e.g. `$order = wc_get_order( $latest_order_id ); $order->get_billing_first_name()` method

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
    function get_last_order_id(){
        global $wpdb;
        $statuses = "wc-completed";

        // Getting last Order ID (max value)
        $results = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT MAX(P.ID) ,PM.meta_value as firstname
                FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts AS P
                INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta AS PM
                ON P.ID = PM.post_id

                 WHERE P.post_type LIKE 'shop_order'
                    AND P.post_status IN ('$statuses')
                    AND PM.meta_key='_billing_first_name'" );
        return $results;
    }
    $latest_order_id = get_last_order_id(); // Last order ID
    $firstname = $latest_order_id->firstname;


    echo $firstname;
```

Comment: echo($order_billing_first_name); just shows the order ID unfortunately.

Comment: print this `print_r($order);` and share the result.

Comment: Ok I think the issue is that the data I want is showing as [current_data:protected] => Array - otherwise your solution would work. Any idea how I can get the protected data? Thanks

Comment: Ok so now this gives: stdClass Object ( [MAX(P.ID)] => 971 [meta_value] => kim ) I just need the 'kim' - any idea how to get that? Thank you very much by the way

Answer (score 0):

You can use join query as well kindly check below query for the same.

```
    SELECT MAX(P.ID) ,PM.meta_value as firstname
    FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts AS P
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta AS PM
    ON P.ID = PM.post_id

     WHERE P.post_type LIKE 'shop_order'
        AND P.post_status IN ('$statuses')
        AND PM.meta_key='_billing_first_name'
```

Just replace your query with given one.

So complete code is following.

```
        <?php
        function get_last_order_id()
        {
            global $wpdb;
            $statuses = "wc-completed";

            // Getting last Order ID (max value)
            $results = $wpdb->get_col( "
                SELECT MAX(P.ID) ,PM.meta_value
                    FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts AS P
                    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta AS PM
                    ON P.ID = PM.post_id

                     WHERE P.post_type LIKE 'shop_order'
                        AND P.post_status IN ('$statuses')
                        AND PM.meta_key='_billing_first_name'
            " );
            return reset($results);
        }

        $latest_order_id = get_last_order_id(); // Last order ID
        echo ($latest_order_id);
```

Comment: $wpdb->get_col return only one column.

Comment: Because here you want MAX(ID) which always return one data only

Comment: If you noticed in query meta_key is firstname so in meta_value you will get the firstname

Comment: It will return 2 columns 1st is ID and second is firstname

Comment: if you notice i just edit the query which you said its working fine I just add the join query to fetch the firstname so if you query is working fine then this will working fine as well

Comment: it does not return ID and firstname. It will return ID only. You need to use get_row.